# Oracle CLOB Field Is Truncated/Gone When Saved With Zeos ZTable

Tags: oracle, delphi, clob, zeos

I started few months ago in a company that uses Oracle 11g and I am building my first application for them.

I have a simple table with a Name as `Varchar2`, a non-index number as `Integer` and a Text Field as `CLOB` to store some rules of each department in HTML.

When the CLOB field is set as `ftMemo` in `TField`, it truncates the texto to only 2910 characters. When the field is set to `ftOraClob` it simples erases the text when I call the `Post` method. I am using ZeosLib to handle the database.

Does anyone knows what Can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of Zeos are you using? On which version of Delphi?

Comment: I downloaded Zeos just last month so I think it is the last version of Zeos, in XE3

Comment: I prefer using XE8 with FireDAC but the company does not have the license for it.

Comment: Old lib  from FireDAC author: http://www.da-soft.com/download/ncoci8/ncoci8-full/details.html
Also https://sourceforge.net/projects/delphioci/

Comment: That link is broken. I've found it in http://www.delphipages.com/comp/ncoci8_v-3130.html and I will check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately this lib is too old, up to D2006. I tried to fix some code but most of it is incompatible with XE3.

Comment: The latest more stable Zeos with best performance is 7.2 branch. Try this one! Or just try our [native Oracle access](http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_126) which works from Delphi 5 to 10 Seattle.